# LFI or RFI from XSS?

Tags: appsec, web-application, xss

Could XSS lead us to the Local File Include or Remote File Include?
I read article that it's possible to upload shell via XSS vulnerability, but I still have no idea how it had been achieved.

Comment: Please provide links to the articles you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server-side "remote file inclusion" vulnerabilities are sometimes classified as XSS, because they include server-side script from another site. I suggest not to use this classification because most people associate XSS with JavaScript.

That being said, JavaScript XSS may lead to a server side remote include: Assume there is a function which allows administrators to upload plugins. If there is a XSS vulnerability somewhere in the same domain, an attacker can use it, to gain access to the administrator-session and upload arbitrary program code, such as [phpshell](http://phpshell.sourceforge.net/).

Furthermore the upload function might not even be intended for plugins but just for images. It might not properly validate the upload, and put the uploaded files into a directory in which .php files are executed, for example.

This might either be a bug because the developers were not aware of the risks, or just a dangerous omission based on the assumptions that only trustworthy people upload files. That's were the XSS vulnerability comes into play.